# What security measures should a application's 'Check for updates' process have?

Tags: c#, wpf, server

I'm creating a firmware update application (in C#, WPF, MVVM, .Net version still up in the air, but I hope to run it on Windows and Mac) that will allow the user to check for updates to both the application itself and for the latest firmware. I plan to use the common method of putting a file on a server that contains the latest version number and a URL to the files. The application will download the file, compare the versions in the file with the local versions, and download the latest files and/or update the application. Universally lacking in the 'how to's' of this method is the topic of security.

My initial thought was to put the "current version file" in a password protected secret folder, but then that seems overkill for a simple XML file. And since the user will be able to download the app from the website anyway, hiding/password protecting the URL to the application seems pointless. Even the firmware, being a binary file running on custom hardware, at first thought seems rather benign from a security perspective. But then again, I don't spend my days thinking of how to hack into systems.

So, in regards to just the process described above, what kinds of security measures should be taken to protect the server, data and user from attacks? And potentially as a bonus question, what security measures can be taken to protect the application update itself? With this, I can at least see the potential to trick the updater into installing malicious code, so a checksum to verify the updated file's integrity would be a minimum there.

Comment: The first thing to think about is what kinds of threats you need to be concerned about. As with your password-protected case, it is pointless to protect against an "attack" which does not harm the integrity of your system. The most dangerous attack in an upgrade scenario would be if an attacker manages to place his own code on the target machine. The usual counter-measure would be some sort of signature verified by the target,

Comment: As a side note, WPF applications don't run on Mac or any other operating system than Windows.

Comment: @KlausGütter: Ok, so my instincts appear correct. It appears that if the application handles the download of the firmware and updates, then we can be reasonably sure we are downloading the file from our servers and therefore its safe as there's no way for an attacker to replace the files. I'd imagine even if the attacker were to use xml deserial injection to replace the URL, a simple check "is the URL on our server?" would prevent that. Same goes for the update process, as long at there's a hash or something as you mention that says "this is our file and it's unmodified"?

Comment: @mm8: Good call. If I plan to do a Mac version too, should I get on Xamarin or Mono ASAP? My plan/hope was that the WPF code base would be similar enough that moving the project to Xamarin/Mono after it's working as a WPF/MVVM would be the easiest route for someone learning (previous exp is only embedded c and HTML/CSS/JS).

Comment: If you plan to target Mac, I would certainly go with something like Xamarin or MAUI from the beginning.

Comment: *a simple check "is the URL on our server?"* - no this is by far not suffient. How do you know that the data you received is in fact from your server and not from a Man in the Middle? *a hash or something* - a hash is not suffient, you need a verifiable signature

Comment: @KlausGütter: Good points. So, then definitely "Signed" software, enforce HTTPS on the WebClient, anything else I should be looking at doing? Side Note: Part of the problem for me here is that I don't know the search terms to get the info I'm looking for from Google/SO, so seeing "man in the middle" and "verifiable signature" opened up quite a bit of helpful resources.